# Remove zeros in an array without creating new method

Tags: java

Im trying to remove zeros from an arrays. I could do a separate method to remove the zeros but i want it in idiomatic way.

```
public int[] commonFactors(int m, int n) {
int[] numbers = new int[n + 1];
for(int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
  if ((m % i == 0) && (n % i == 0)) {
    numbers[i] = i;
  }
}
return numbers;//or return DelZero(numbers);
}
```

And here is the method to remove all the zeros:

```
public int[] DelZero(int numbers[]) {
int zeroCount=0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  if (numbers[i] == 0) {
    zeroCount++;
  }
} 

int[] newNumber = new int[numbers.length-zeroCount];
int j =0;
for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
  if (numbers[i] != 0) {
    newNumber[j++] = numbers[i];
  }
}
return newNumber;
}
```

So the crux of my question is this: *Is there a way to remove the zeros without creating a new method?* (In this case without DelZero.)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I want to remove all the zeros in an arrays for example if i invoke commonFactors(28,49) and the output will be { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0....}. Is there a way to remove the zeros without creating a new method? In this case without DelZero.

Comment: When you create a primitive int array, it's filled with the default initialization value, which is 0. Consider using a `List<Integer>` instead.

Comment: Didn't understand you question. But you can make your DelZero function in place rather than creating another array, reducing code also. Don't add the zeros in first place by using either a dynamic array structure like a list or a simple array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java8, you can exploit `Stream` to do it very easily:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{0,0,7,6,5,0,1,0,4};
int[] arr_without_zeros = IntStream.of(arr).filter(i -> i != 0).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example from which you should be able to answer your question:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RemoveZeros {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] zeroArray = { 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5 };

        System.out.println("Original array: " + Arrays.toString(zeroArray));

        int nonZeros = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < zeroArray.length; i++) {
            if (zeroArray[i] != 0) {
                nonZeros++;
            }
        }

        int[] tempArray = new int[nonZeros];
        int tempIndex = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < zeroArray.length; j++) {
            if (zeroArray[j] != 0) {
                tempArray[tempIndex] = zeroArray[j];
                tempIndex++;
            }
        }

        zeroArray = tempArray;

        System.out.println("Modified array: " + Arrays.toString(zeroArray));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Original array: [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5]
Modified array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using java.util.List instead of primitive array. Suddenly everything is a lot easier...

```
public List<Integer> commonFactors(int m, int n) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
        if ((m % i == 0) && (n % i == 0) && i != 0) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}
```